# Java: I don't get it why text reader start reading text from second line

Tags: java, io

I don't why my code is skipping first line from txt file. I'am confused because this code was working fine at first...
Here is the code:

```
    InputStream input = event.getFile().getInputstream();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            String red;
            int brojac = 0;
            String content = "";
            String billNumber = "840000000096362741";
            if(br.readLine() == null){
                throw new WrongFileException("Format fajla nije dobar!");
            }
            while ((red = br.readLine()) != null) {
                content = red;
                treasuryStatHeader.setTshStatFileContent(content);
                System.out.println(content.substring(0, 20));
                brojac++;
                System.out.println(brojac + " BROJACCCCCCC");
                if (brojac == 1) {
                .
                .
                .
                } else {...}
```

Comment: Can we see your text file?

Comment: you are calling br.readLine() one time before while itself, that is not going to print.

Comment: Are you closing the InputStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of your first `if(br.readLine() == null){` This place where you tell your file reader to read the first line and go to the next line. What you can do is move the null check into your while loop.

```
boolean firstLine = true;
while (red = br.readLine()) {
  if(firstline && red == null) {
    throw new WrongFileException("Format fajla nije dobar!");
  }
  firstLine = false;
  if(null == red) {
    continue;
  }
  content = red;
  treasuryStatHeader.setTshStatFileContent(content);
  // [...]
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Can't believe I didn't see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[BufferedRead.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) consumes the first line in your `if` condition here:

`if(br.readLine() == null){`